# when i scroll my website my navbar hidden in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am stuck with a problem when am trying to scroll website my navbar is going hidden when it goes to the second page, please tell me why it's happening, or to tell any tutorial or course those i refer

> index.html

This is the index.html file where i wrote my whole project code
and here i also used fontawesome for icons

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
      <!-- <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
      <title>Website</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <!-- header Start -->
    
      <div class="header" id="top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
          <div class="container  p-1">
            <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold text-white" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: white; font-size: 30px;"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-uppercase ">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link " href="#">Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" >
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Price</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <section class="header-section">
          <div class="center-div">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold">We are The Web Developer</h1>
            <p>We create the best Website</p>
            <div class="header-button">
              <a href="#">About Us</a>
              <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    
      <!-- header End -->
    
    
      <!-- extra header div start -->
    
      <section class="header-extra">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="extra-div col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa-2x fas fa-desktop"></i></a>
              <h2>WEBSITE DEVELOPMENT</h2>
              <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, dolorem reiciendis! Eos ratione dolorum
                accusamus nesciunt mollitia atque omnis officiis vel inventore minima, eum fuga, qui modi molestias, debitis
                minus?</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="extra-div col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 mt-1">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa-2x fas fa-trophy"></i></a>
              <h2>DOMAIN AND HOSTING</h2>
              <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, dolorem reiciendis! Eos ratione dolorum
                accusamus nesciunt mollitia atque omnis officiis vel inventore minima, eum fuga, qui modi molestias, debitis
                minus?</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="extra-div col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 mt-1">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa-2x fas fa-magic"></i></a>
              <h2>SUPPORT 24/7</h2>
              <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, dolorem reiciendis! Eos ratione dolorum
                accusamus nesciunt mollitia atque omnis officiis vel inventore minima, eum fuga, qui modi molestias, debitis
                minus?</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    
      <!-- extra header div end -->
    
      <!-- offer section start -->
        <section class="serviceOffer" id="servicediv">
          <div class="container heading text-center">
            <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold">OUR WORK PROCESS</h1>
            <p class="text-center">Before working of on any project there is a flow. We believes in N2DT.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12 servicediv" >
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
                     <i class="fa-2x fad fa-sort-amount-up-alt mt-4" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: lightskyblue; padding: 13px; border-radius: 50%;"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
                    <h2>NEED</h2>
                    <p>Every project starts because of some need and we understand. Clients has diffrent prospective about project and we believe in our client.</p>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
                    <i class="fa-2x fal fa-palette mt-4" aria-hidden="true"  style="background-color: lightskyblue; padding: 13px; border-radius: 50%;"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
                    <h2>Designing</h2>
                    <p>Our creative designers work together for best outcome. which help our development team to reduce UI flows & timeline.</p>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
                    <i class="fa-2x far fa-code mt-4"  aria-hidden="true"  style="background-color: lightskyblue; padding: 13px; border-radius: 50%;"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
                    <h2>Development</h2>
                    <p>After Designing we collabrates with team and start working on projects.</p>
                 </div>
                 
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
                    <i class="fa-2x far fa-cogs mt-4"  aria-hidden="true"  style="background-color: lightskyblue; padding: 13px; border-radius: 50%; "></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
                    <h2>Testing</h2>
                    <p>Testing is very important and final step in every project we created. We don't want to compramise for our clients.</p>
                 </div>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-10 offset-1 offset-lg-0">
             <img src="https://www.swapneal.co.in/images/new/SVG/work-process.svg" style="display: flex;">
            </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
    
    
        <!-- footer start -->
        <div class="footer bg-dark">
          <p class="text-center text-white mb-0 p-3">© 2021 abc solution All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- footer end -->
      
      
    
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to just add `background-color` to `.fixed-top` class and add `padding-top` to `.header-section` class.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/yu1azfed/2/

```css
.header-section {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.fixed-top {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <!-- <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- header Start -->

  <div class="header" id="top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
      <div class="container  p-1">
        <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold text-white" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: white; font-size: 30px;"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-uppercase ">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Home </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Price</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="header-section">
      <div class="center-div">
        <h1 class="font-weight-bold">We are The Web Developer</h1>
        <p>We create the best Website</p>
        <div class="header-button">
          <a href="#">About Us</a>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <!-- header End -->


  <!-- extra header div start -->

  <section class="header-extra">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="extra-div col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-2x fas fa-desktop"></i></a>
          <h2>WEBSITE DEVELOPMENT</h2>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, dolorem reiciendis! Eos ratione dolorum accusamus nesciunt mollitia atque omnis officiis vel inventore minima, eum fuga, qui modi molestias, debitis minus?
          </p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="extra-div col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 mt-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-2x fas fa-trophy"></i></a>
          <h2>DOMAIN AND HOSTING</h2>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, dolorem reiciendis! Eos ratione dolorum accusamus nesciunt mollitia atque omnis officiis vel inventore minima, eum fuga, qui modi molestias, debitis minus?
          </p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="extra-div col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 mt-1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-2x fas fa-magic"></i></a>
          <h2>SUPPORT 24/7</h2>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, dolorem reiciendis! Eos ratione dolorum accusamus nesciunt mollitia atque omnis officiis vel inventore minima, eum fuga, qui modi molestias, debitis minus?
          </p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- extra header div end -->

  <!-- offer section start -->
  <section class="serviceOffer" id="servicediv">
    <div class="container heading text-center">
      <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold">OUR WORK PROCESS</h1>
      <p class="text-center">Before working of on any project there is a flow. We believes in N2DT.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12 servicediv">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
              <i class="fa-2x fad fa-sort-amount-up-alt mt-4" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: lightskyblue; padding: 13px; border-radius: 50%;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
              <h2>NEED</h2>
              <p>Every project starts because of some need and we understand. Clients has diffrent prospective about project and we believe in our client.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
              <i class="fa-2x fal fa-palette mt-4" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: lightskyblue; padding: 13px; border-radius: 50%;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
              <h2>Designing</h2>
              <p>Our creative designers work together for best outcome. which help our development team to reduce UI flows & timeline.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
              <i class="fa-2x far fa-code mt-4" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: lightskyblue; padding: 13px; border-radius: 50%;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
              <h2>Development</h2>
              <p>After Designing we collabrates with team and start working on projects.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
              <i class="fa-2x far fa-cogs mt-4" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: lightskyblue; padding: 13px; border-radius: 50%; "></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
              <h2>Testing</h2>
              <p>Testing is very important and final step in every project we created. We don't want to compramise for our clients.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-10 offset-1 offset-lg-0">
          <img src="https://www.swapneal.co.in/images/new/SVG/work-process.svg" style="display: flex;">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- footer start -->
  <div class="footer bg-dark">
    <p class="text-center text-white mb-0 p-3">© 2021 abc solution All rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- footer end -->



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
html css bootstr
```

Answer (score 0):

`nav{ position: fixed; }`
Add that to your style.css